# How do you set a Xaml defined, Window.Resource Image programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I have a xaml file that has a series of resources that I use in my window.  Specifically, I have two `Image` objects.  Instead of encoding a URI location, I need to set these images in the constructor of my Window.  How can I do this?

I've searched and searched, and I've tried to set the image `.Source` property.  Nothing has worked.  For reference, here is how these images are declared in my xaml file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="iUpdate" />
    <Image x:Key="iDelete" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And here is how they are used for a button's content:

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button Name="UpdateChange" Content="{StaticResource iUpdate}" Width="24" />
                        <Button Name="DeleteChange" Content="{StaticResource iDelete}" Width="24" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding name}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Here is my failed attempt at setting the image's source.

```
        //In my constructor...
        // iUpdate is a property on the Window
        iUpdate = (Image)FindResource("iUpdate");
                    iUpdate = new Image();
        iUpdate.Source = ImageHelpers.ConvertBitmapToImageSource(Common.LoadImage("edit.ico"));
```

FYI, I can't set the source in my xaml file because the call to `Common.LoadImage(...)` is a special call that resolves the location of the file.  This could vary significantly from user-to-user, which is why the helper-method exists in the first place.

Comment: Why don't you just bind to two view model properties? You would create the Image controls in XAML as the Button's Content and bind their Source property to the view model properties (or properties of your MainWindow class if you prefer that). Having controls as resources is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @Clemens  I'll look into that.  This is my first attempt at WPF.  That approach might work.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Image controls as resources, you could declare and bind to two properties in your MainWindow class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        UpdateImage = ImageHelpers.ConvertBitmapToImageSource(...);
        DeleteImage = ImageHelpers.ConvertBitmapToImageSource(...);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageSource UpdateImage { get; set; }
    public ImageSource DeleteImage { get; set; }
}
```

You would bind to these properties by assigning a Name to the Window

```
<Window ... x:Name="window">
```

and declare an ElementName binding:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="{Binding UpdateImage, ElementName=window}"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

---

And to answer your question, your problem is that you assign a new Image instance to the `iUpdate` field right after assigning it to the resource instance. Your code should have looked like this:

```
iUpdate = (Image)Resources["iUpdate"];
iUpdate.Source = ImageHelpers.ConvertBitmapToImageSource(...);
```